# Saving tabbed content individually or as one

Tags: usability, forms

So users can login to this system and choose to edit an item from their list. I'm trying to figure out the best way to allow users to save the tabs they edit.

From the design below, is it clear that as a user you'd be able to edit each tab, in any order, and then save them all (instead of having to save each tabs data before moving to the next)?

Dots will appear next to tabs with unsaved content.

Is this a good approach to take or is it going to be confusing for the user?

This is a single page JavaScript web app.

Any ideas / suggestions / views etc are appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you let user edit in any order?

Comment: Is there any reason why the user wouldn't want to save all tabs?

Comment: @Midas The user may want to only edit content on a specific tab and then republish. This avoids them having to step through the whole process just to make an edit on say Tab 4.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Hmm, not that I can think of.

Comment: @Mac - Problem solved!

Comment: I think the data which is unsaved must be save temporarily somewhere in local cache.

Answer (score 1):

As a user i would feel more comfortable if it the form autosaves the things that i am typing in every field and the publish button stays always there and after i have finished by pressing it, my changes get published. Or you can change the button save to say draft and stays static, when pressed it saves the draft.

Comment: This is more of an implementation answer than a UX one. Users couldn't give two hoots if it's AngularJS or not. They just care about the overall experience. Can you elaborate on that part?

Comment: Maybe i didnt wrote it as a user would, just edited it now.